# Selection of Boolean in pandas between one main column and another optional column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sorry, I couldn't find any good title for this question. Please feel free to edit the title if you find some suitable title for it.

I have a dataframe and it has two columns `Val1` and `ExtraVal`; both `Val1` and `ExtraVal` contain boolean values. My main column is `Val1` but at the same time i am supposed to take values from `ExtraVal` too if it is only True and that True also matches with True values in the `Val1 column`.

I cannot use `df[val1] & df[ExtraVal]` because then that statement will remove the True from Val1 column when ExtraVal becomes False.

and I cannot use or statement either between these two because then it becomes True if `ExtraColumn` is true even though `val1` column  is false.

Hope this sample data explains more clearly what I meant.

Sample Dataframe looks like this

```
Val1 ExtraVal
True,False
False,False
False,False
True,True
False,True
False,True
True,True
```

Output I want is

```
Val1,ExtraVal
True,False
True,True
True,True
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need:

```
df1 = df[df['Val1']]
print (df1)
   Val1  ExtraVal
0  True     False
3  True      True
6  True      True
```

Comment: thanks. So I dont need to even check with ExtraVal column at all ? I was thinking more like a solution where checking with ExtraVal also involves. As this was just a sample dataframe and in my actual code I should also check with columns like ExtraVal as there are going to be more such columns.

Comment: @fireandwind - If need select all rows if `True` in `Val1` column, the best is use `df[df['Val1']]`

Comment: @fireandwind - If need something more complicted, can you explain more?

Comment: I dont know how do I explain, but In a simple term, I want exactly the same thing what you have answered but I wanted to involve ExtraVal column on this too while doing boolean selection.  Sorry, I couldnt explain more. by writing.....

Comment: The reason I wanted to do such thing is that, there will have many columns like Val1 and ExtraVal and I need to check individually with related Val column and their Extraval column

Comment: @fireandwind - OK, so `ExtraVal` values should change `True` values of `Val1` column? Is it possible?

Comment: No, Extra Val column cannot change Val1 column at all. It should only return its values if Val1 columns are True ( which you have answered already and it works perfectly).

May be this helps in explaining 
Lets Say there are two main columns Val1 and Val2
now Val1 should check with ExtraVal1 and Val2 should check ExtraVal2
and final output is something like similar of what you have answered. 

Sorry if this was unclear, may be I can invite you in discussion chat ? .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174721/discussion-between-jezrael-and-fireandwind).